# Dynamo DB Projecting additional attributes in existing GSI having billions of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a dynamo db table having almost a billion records in it. It has 4 different GSI. I need to project few more attributes to one of the GSI. What is the best approach to do so?
I thought two options:

1. Delete the GSI where I want to project additional attributes and recreate. ( 2 step process)-may take long
2. Create another new GSI to fulfill my need- still may take long as I have a billion records in it but may be a bit faster than #1. But, cost increase significantly than #1 as I am adding new GSI.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way on this?

Comment: We did it option 1